# Liquibase: procedures rollback

Tags: liquibase, procedure, rollback, skip

I have an .xml file with sql procedure with runOnChange = 'true'. And this procedure was updated last to DATACHANGELOG table.

```
...
    <changeSet author="rozmaryn" id="040920201357" runOnChange="true" runInTransaction="true">
         <sqlFile path="storedProcedures/procedureFirst.sql"
                  encoding="UTF-8"
                  relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    </changeSet>
```

But if I rollback for example "rollbackCount=5", I have an error.
I know that I can add `<rollback></rollback>` node, but since I have runOnChange I would like to skip  rollback of the procedure by command. It is possible?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?  I don't think rollback cares about the runOnChange ='true' because it is not accessing if it needs to be ran, it just is trying to assess if it was within rollback count.